# why I cannot initialize this pointer with a string?

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
//a pointer to the first block of screen
int far *SCR = (int far *) 0xB8000000; 

(SCR +  6 * 80 + 31) += "HELLO HELLO HELLO";
```

In the code above, I defined `SCR` which is a pointer to the first block of the screen in text mode. It works correctly and I can write on the screen in text mode as below:

```
#define WHITE 3840
*(SCR +  6 * 80 + 31) = 'h' + WHITE;
*(SCR +  6 * 80 + 32) = 'e' + WHITE;
*(SCR +  6 * 80 + 33) = 'l' + WHITE;
*(SCR +  6 * 80 + 34) = 'l' + WHITE;
*(SCR +  6 * 80 + 35) = 'o' + WHITE;
```

but when I want to write something long in the screen and when I attempt to write as below I see an error of `Lvalue required` from the last line in the code written below:

```
#define WHITE 3840
for(int i = 31; i < 36; i++)
   *(SCR + 6 * 80 + i) = WHITE;
(SCR + 6 * 80 + 31) += "hello";
```

Why I cannot have access to the pointer such as above and how I can fix my problem in writing long words and sentences with the pointer `SCR` I defined?

Comment: `+=` does not automatically loop over the elements of an array.

Comment: @Barmar let me see if it can be fixed without the `+=`. but then how I can add pen color to that if I am supposed not to use `+=`?

Comment: @Barmar no it still errors as `Lvalue required`

Comment: OT: As writing `char`s I'd declare `SCR` this way: `char far * SCR = (char far *) 0xB8000000;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do something like:

```
(SCR + 6 * 80 + 31) += "hello";
```

because `"hello"` is a pointer that points to an array of `char` that's been initialized with the characters `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`,  etc.  And you can't add pointers to pointers (nor would it make sense for your problem even if you were allowed to).

If you want to output a string to a location pointed to by `SCR` plus some offset, write a function to make it less painful. That's what functions are for:

```
void write_to_screen( int row, int col, char const* s, int attr)
{
    int offs = row * 80 + col;

    for (;*s != 0; ++s) {
        SCR[offs++] = attr | *s;
    }
}

// call it like so:
write_to_screen( 6, 30, "hello", WHITE);
```

or something like that (you may need to adjust the details of where & how attributes and characters get written, since I don't recall the details of writing to the screen buffer in real mode).

Comment: if we initialize `SCR[offs++]` with `attr` and then with `*s` the so the `attr` value will be lost. cannot we use `+=' at any case?

Comment: what is this `SCR[offs++] = attr | *s;`? I don't understand `|` between them? would you explain?

Comment: @MelikaBarzegaranHosseini: it is a bitwise or operator.  The value of WHITE is `0x0f00` in hex, if `s` is pointing to the letter `'h'` (which has a hex value of `0x68`) the result of `attr | *s` would be `0x0f68`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define WHITE 3840
char *hello = "hello";
for (int i = 0; hello[i]; i++) {
    *(SCR + 6 * 80 + 31 + i) = WHITE + hello[i];
}
```

Comment: why `for (int i = 0; hello[i]; i++)` ? I don't understand the second part of the for loop.

Comment: and I have lots of strings to write. Isn't there a shorter way so that I wouldn't be made to write one for loop for each string?

Comment: Put it in a function, and pass the string as an argument.